# How can I diagnose and reduce the number of dropped packets coming in from the WAN ethernet interface?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, firewall, ethernet

I have a couple Ubuntu servers each running as a firewall/router. I've noticed one has a much higher RX-drop count than the other. The drops seems to jump in spurts. This last netstat shows about 2.6% dropped:

```
$ sudo netstat -ni
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0      1500  1715434      0  45323 0        672858      0      0      0 BMORU
eth1      1500     7146      0      0 0         18148      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536   200950      0      0 0        200950      0      0      0 LRU
wlan0     1500   679702      0      0 0       1315730      0      0      0 BMRU
```

This is much higher than the other which shows ~ 0.01%. How can I figure out what is causing it?

So far, I've tried to increase the interface ring rx buffer size:

```
$ sudo ethtool -g eth0
Ring parameters for eth0:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:     4096
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     4096
Current hardware settings:
RX:     256
RX Mini:    0
RX Jumbo:   0
TX:     256

$ sudo ethtool -G eth0 rx 4096 tx 4096
```

I also thought I could drop some packets at the physical layer by using ntuple filters, but I couldn't modify any of these rules using ethtool on this Intel i210 NIC.

FYI here is some more info from ethtool. (I cannot change any of these parameters either)

```
$ sudo ethtool -c eth0
Coalesce parameters for eth0:
Adaptive RX: off  TX: off
stats-block-usecs: 0
sample-interval: 0
pkt-rate-low: 0
pkt-rate-high: 0

rx-usecs: 3
rx-frames: 0
rx-usecs-irq: 0
rx-frames-irq: 0

tx-usecs: 0
tx-frames: 0
tx-usecs-irq: 0
tx-frames-irq: 0

rx-usecs-low: 0
rx-frames-low: 0
tx-usecs-low: 0
tx-frames-low: 0

rx-usecs-high: 0
rx-frames-high: 0
tx-usecs-high: 0
tx-frames-high: 0
```

Comment: because of [this Q/A](https://serverfault.com/questions/1015896/linux-server-dropping-rx-packets-in-netif-receive-skb-core) I heard about [this tool `dropwatch`](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/09/05/finding-out-where-packets-are-being-dropped/). From 2017 - no idea whether it still works.

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting and reading, I realized this is just because I have ipv6 disabled as a kernel boot parameter. I thought there were packets being dropped from the ethernet card, but it is simply showing that the ipv6 packets are being dropped as they have no support in the kernel.

This link helped me figure this out: https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017478

So instead of disabling ipv6 in the grub command line, I simply went back to disabling in sysctl.conf, e.g. (/etc/sysctl.d/20-local.conf)

```
# disable ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Now there are no more drops and ipv6 is still disabled. It is a little weird that one server was worse than the other, but they both work now.